# How to display links from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a form with a multiline textbox that is a description.  I was wondering is there anyway  to make it so that if i type in a url like www.anywebsiteintheworld.com in that multiline textbox along with other text and later display that information where the link in the middle of the description is clickable?

Right now I grab the information with `textbox.Text.Trim()` and display it as a `label.Text` and it doesnt work.

Comment: You need to use a rich editor for that, like http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx, or http://ckeditor.com/ or other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in a normal HTML textbox. You'll need a JavaScript based rich text editor such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).